# Anyone want to try programming an extension for the world's easiest sms provider?

Tags: extension, sms, civisms

I would really like to have an extension for the NowSMS provider, and I've been through the documentation and creating an extension with civix, but there is just too much of it that is over my head. Would someone please consider creating one?

In my opinion, NowSMS has the easiest API of all the providers since there is no security or encryption of any kind. It's literally just http in and out with 3 variables, the two phone numbers and the message body.

You don't even need a working NowSMS installation to test it. You can use a browser and a small .htm file and a php script that can receive http get variables. As long as it uses http get and supports the three variables, it will work.

Ideally it would support a customizable url, and the attributes block would include the phone number, like any of the other providers.

For a bit of background, NowSMS runs through a cellphone instead of over the internet, so your only bill is to pay the phone bill. At $30 USD for the phone, the tipping point is 4000 texts per month, where NowSMS becomes more cost effective than Twilio.

Another cool feature is that NowSMS runs an app on Android phone, meaning you can use the cell phone as a cell phone, and then you can log into civicrm and send a bulk message, and you'll see it in the phone's text message app. When people reply, the message will be received by the phone's message app as normal, and it will also be copied and received by civicrm. Someone can be using the phone while someone else is using civicrm to send through the phone in the background.

So how about it, anyone interested in releasing a really easy extension?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the api it seems to be very simple one to implement. You can do it by using reference from https://github.com/osseed/com.osseed.sms.mysmsmantra